# Can I omit second "will" in a compound sentence?

Tags: modal-verbs

Is it correct if I omit the second "will" in this sentence:

```
I will paint the walls, and you **will** take out the garbage.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will paint the walls and you, the floor.

BUT:
I will paint the walls and you will take out the garbage.

That is a compound sentence and therefore needs two verbs. And the verb in full would take will. No, the second will cannot be omitted.

However, if there were just one subject pronoun or subject, you could omit will, and also other auxiliary verbs.

- I will paint the walls and take out the garbage.
- She is leaving home and quitting her job.

Bear in mind: In everyday speech, we usually use contracted forms.

**I'll** do this and **you'll** do that.

Comment: Yep! I'd add two little things: 

That since will can be abbreviated to" 'll", if you took out the "'ll" you wouldn't be abbreviating your sentence by even a single syllable.

That sentences like "I'll go to the shops and you make the dinner" are common enough, but the second part of such sentences is actually a gentle form of the imperative.

Comment: @Jaime That is called contraction not abbreviation. Anyway, the contracted form does not change the sentence.

Comment: I stand corrected. Aside from that quibble, my observation stands. You're very welcome.

Comment: @Jaime I'll go to the shop and you make the dinner.  is a different meaning altogether.  And I don't think you pointing out the contraction adds to the actual basis of the question.

Comment: That's what I said. You were expressing irritation on another question a few minutes ago; let me express some now: I was clearly (or so I thought) warning the questioner against mixing the two forms up, and implicitly suggesting why it is that "will" (or its contraction "'ll") needs to be repeated.

Comment: Another small question. You don't use a comma before "and". How is right?

Comment: @Kostya You don't need commas in compound sentences connected by and: He plays tennis and she plays basketball.